# How to start an array list from second element but still get the first one at the end

Tags: java, android, kotlin, arraylist

I'm trying to start my ArrayList from the second element so I did something like this:

books.elementAt(2)

and it works, but that omits the first element and I just want to skip it but still get access to it. How can I do it?

I dont to re order my arraylist, I want to keep it same way:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5

What I need its: if I look at the second book, easily go back to  first book. I'm displaying info books in ImageView in a RecyclerView.

Comment: The second element is at books.elementAt(1).

Comment: Need more detail. Is this in a for loop? You want to iterate the whole list in a circular manner starting somewhere besides the first element?

Comment: I want to display something in imageviews depend on the element of my arrayList, and move to first and third element

Answer (score 0):

Without just moving the element to the end of the ArrayList? Most straight forward way would be to mark your starting point and use two loops.

```
val start = 1;
for (i in start..(args.size - 1))
    println(args[i])
for (i in 0..(start - 1))
    println(args[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm guessing correctly at what you're doing, you can create a temporary rearranged list like this:

```
for (element in list.run { drop(1) + take(1) }) {
    println(element)
}
```

With a long list, you can use a Sequence to do it more efficiently (it doesn't actually create new lists):

```
for (element in list.asSequence().run { drop(1) + take(1) }) {
    println(element)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a list out of the given list such that the new list starts from the second element but still get the first one at the end, you can use [`Collections#rotate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int)) as follows:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = List.of("One", "Two", "Three", "Four");

        List<String> rotated = new ArrayList<String>(list);
        Collections.rotate(rotated, list.size() - 1);
        System.out.println(rotated);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
[Two, Three, Four, One]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've had a few ways to do it posted, here's a more Kotlin-y approach

```
val stuff = listOf(1,2,3,4,5)
println(stuff.drop(1) + stuff.first())

>>> [2, 3, 4, 5, 1]
```

it really depends on what you're doing and why you're doing it!